# Hide scrollbar in Midori

Tags: browser, scroll, hide, midori

I'm launching Midori in full screen, from the terminal. Using it on my Raspberry Pi in kiosk mode. It does however show the scrollbar (vertical and horizontal) even when the page is smaller than the screen. Is there any way I can hide the scroll bars from a client point of view? I guess I can hide it by modifying the web sites CSS, but as said I want Midori to hide it no matter what the site says.

Answer (score 1):

Are using any Desktop environment ? Or just running it without any window manager. I had similar problems when i was running midori on top of xorg without window manager. I am using the matchbox-window-manager now which is working ok so far.